# xslt : wildcard condition check and read the values using wildcard

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

input xml to XSLT 1.0

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <MESSAGE xmlns="http://MessangerApplication/datamodel">
            <LAST_UPDATED_BY>-2</LAST_UPDATED_BY>
            <LAST_UPDATE_DATE>2016-07-13T15:02:34.000-07:00</LAST_UPDATE_DATE>
            <PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ACC_CONTACT_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE>2016-07-13T15:02:34.000-07:00</PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ACC_CONTACT_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE>
            <ADDRESSES>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <ADDR_ID>-10197894</ADDR_ID>
                    <LAST_UPDATED_BY>-2</LAST_UPDATED_BY>
                    <LAST_UPDATE_DATE>2016-07-13T15:54:19.000-07:00</LAST_UPDATE_DATE>
                    <PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE/>
                </ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LAST_UPDATED_BY>5309</LAST_UPDATED_BY>
                    <LAST_UPDATE_DATE>2016-07-13T15:55:32.000-07:00</LAST_UPDATE_DATE>
                    <PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE>2016-07-13T16:53:21.000-07:00</PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE>
                </ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LAST_UPDATED_BY>5309</LAST_UPDATED_BY>
                    <LAST_UPDATE_DATE>2016-07-13T15:55:32.000-07:00</LAST_UPDATE_DATE>
                    <PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE>2016-07-13T15:06:12.000-07:00</PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE>
                </ADDRESS>
            </ADDRESSES>
            <PHONES>
                <PHONE>
                    <LAST_UPDATED_BY>-2</LAST_UPDATED_BY>
                </PHONE>
            </PHONES>
        </MESSAGE>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

below is my XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://MessangerApplication/datamodel">
        <xsl:template match="//ns:MESSAGE">
            <ns:Account_Address>
<!-- START : First choose block -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="(('-2' != ns:LAST_UPDATED_BY or '-2' != ns:PHONES/ns:PHONE/ns:LAST_UPDATED_BY) and 
                        (ns:PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ACC_CONTACT_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE != ''))">
                        <xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="ns:LAST_UPDATE_DATE"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="prevDate" select="ns:PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ACC_CONTACT_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE"/>

                        <testingAccount>true</testingAccount>

                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <testingAccount>false</testingAccount>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
<!-- END : First choose block -->     
**<!-- START : Second choose block -->**           
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="((ns:ADDRESSES/ns:ADDRESS[ns:LAST_UPDATED_BY] != '-2') and 
                        (ns:ADDRESSES/ns:ADDRESS[ns:PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE != '']))">
                        <!-- 
                            here i want to read LAST_UPDATE_DATE and PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE
                        -->
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <addressTesting>false</addressTesting>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
**<!-- END : Second choose block -->**
            </ns:Account_Address>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So in XSLT (Second choose block) i want to read below values and stop traversing further when it finds the value of below two tags

```
1) LAST_UPDATE_DATE (path : ADDRESSES/LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
2) PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE (path : ADDRESSES/PREV_MODIFIED_DATE_ADDR_IN_CUSTOM_TABLE)
```

[image]

please suggest how can i implement the logic in Second choose block (mentioned in XSLT), many thanks

***I am using XSLT 1.0***

Comment: Please specify XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay Question updated, i am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: In that case I will leave it to others.

Comment: "*to compare the dates, i am using the this solution XSLT : compare date timezone*" I don't see that you do.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i am using the solution which you have give to me, but it is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have no idea what your question here is.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have modified the question. can you please let me know if any further details required